# Prevent a service from being killed

Tags: android, android-service

How to prevent a `Service` which should run without showing a notification from being killed even if the app is killed?

I'm trying to run a `Service` which tracks GPS location after every 10 minutes and I want my `Service` to run continuously even if the app is killed. I've already tried `startForeground()` but it also gives me a notification. How can I get a solution without notification?

Comment: start a Started type of service and not the Bound one, even if it is killed by system it will be relaunched as soon as enough resources  are available

Answer (score 1):

You can return `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` from your `Service` `onStartCommand`. So when your service is killed, the service will be restarted and last delivered intent will be sent.

Also you can return `START_STICKY` to auto-restart the service killed by android.

So if even user swipes close the app from open apps screen, your service will restart.

Ref http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,int,int)

Answer (score 1):

Add [START_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY).
This causes service to restart.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `START_STICKY` or apply wake lock which calls the service immediately as soon as it stops.